# Javascript - Add specific keypress event inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to assign a keypress event to an element within a for loop.  I know that there are issues with assigning events while in a for loop dynamically, and I have solved that for the "click" event however I am at a loss for how it should work for the keypress.  (probably because I don't really understand how the "click" one works to begin with... closure avoidance is not something I fully get)

The basic setup is that there is a for loop that will print out a number of different textareas and a div underneath them.  Pressing the div will send the text in the text area to the right person.  What I would like to have happen is that the same message should be sent if the enter button is pressed within the text area.

```
for( var i in people){

 var message = $('<textarea></textarea>').appendTo(container);
 message.on( "keypress",  function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode==13){
   // code does make it in here ...
   sendMessage(people[i].name); // but this never gets run
  }
 });

 var messageButton= $('<div>Send</div>').appendTo(container);
 messageButton.on( "click", sendMessage(people[i].name) );                

}

var sendMessage = function(to) {
 return function(){
  /* do the sending of the message to the right person */
 }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand the following?

Why does the click function work in the first place? I am not understanding why we have to put return around the function block.

Why doesn't the keypress function work similarly?

On a more general level, how does keypress work to begin with.  The function(e) should not work because 'e' isn't anything, where does that even get set?

Comment: Wrapped inside of a function due to iteration, otherwise you would be only invoking the message sent for the last item in the array.

sendMessage probably gets ran, however the inner-method that is wrapped is probably not being invoked.

Comment: If you are using jQuery anyway, you might want to use `$.each` instead of a for loop. Avoids the whole problem. There are other event better solutions, but that would be a very simple one. If you want to learn more about the general solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `keypress` in the code is that it will always send the message to latest person in people as at the moment when it is executed, `i` will have the latest value in it.

I probably would use `forEach` instead:

```
people.forEach(function (person) {
    var message = $('<textarea></textarea>').appendTo(container);

    // you can use keypress - http://api.jquery.com/keypress/#keypress-eventData-handler
    // see the examples in the reference
    message.keypress(function (e) {                     
      if (e.which === 13) {
          // here you should invoke the function returned by the sendMessage
          sendMessage(person.name)();
      }
    });

    var messageButton= $('<div>Send</div>').appendTo(container);

    messageButton.click(sendMessage(person.name));                
  });
```

with this approach you do not need to wrap the function in the sendMessage and can just call the original function in the corresponding event handler.

Comment: I have implemented this approach and found it to be a success.  Can you help me understand (or link me to a resource which explains) the syntax of sendMessage(person.name)();  (two sets of paranthesis...) what is that doing exactly?

Comment: Well, `()` is just executing the function (if the left-side expression returns it). Consider the following example: `var f = function () { }; f();`. In your code the `sendMessage` returns a function so it can be written as `var f = sendMessage(...); f();` or in a short form just `sendMessage(...)();`

Answer (score 0):

Clean example using jQuery. You should read more about jQuery and closures for iterations so you can easily understand what is going on.

```
$.each(people, function (person) {
  var $message = $('<textarea></textarea>').appendTo(container);
  var $button = $('<div>Send</div>').appendTo(container);
  var send = sendMessage(person.name);

  // Keypress handler
  $message.keypress(function (e) {                     
    if (e.which === 13) { // on enter do the following
      send();
    }
  });

  $button.click(send);                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using a handwritten closure:

http://jsfiddle.net/M5NsS/1/

```
var people = {
    'p1': {
        name: 'john'
    },
        'p2': {
        name: 'bob'
    },
        'p3': {
        name: 'jim'
    }
};

var container = $('#container');

for (var i in people) {

    (function (name) {
        var message = $('<textarea></textarea>').appendTo(container);
        message.keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                sendMessage(name);
            }
        });

        var messageButton = $('<div>Send</div>').appendTo(container);
        messageButton.click(function () {
            sendMessage(name)
        });
    })(people[i].name);

}

function sendMessage(to) {
    console.log(to);
}
```

As others have stated, the issue is that the event is bound with the last reference to 'i' in the loop. Using a closure solves this issue while still allowing you to use your for..in loop.

Another thing to note is that if you are not dynamically appending these elements to the DOM *after* binding, there is no reason to use jquery's .on(). You can directly bind .keypress() and .click() handlers to the elements, as seen in my fiddle and on @AlexAtNet's answer.

But it's clunky, and I would just use jquerys $.each as others have already suggested.